# Temporary dyld_shared_cache taking a lot of space

Tags: xcode, disk-space, xcode-simulator

I am developing an application with Flutter and using an iOs simulator (iPhone 8 13.4).
I noticed that while I am running my application (I am using VSCode), a lot of space is taken by some files.
After some research, I found out that it is dyld_shared_cache_arm64e cache is taking a dump every minute which takes 1.73GB consistently. Location -  `/private/var/folders/rc/9jqgfj8148z8cfyz_9qht07m0000gn/T/TemporaryItems`

I have 500GB of free space in my Mac, so after 3 hours my Mac is filled up. I haven't found any solution on the internet to stop caching apart from restarting my computer. I don't want to restart my mac every 3 hours. Any solution here?

macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E266)
Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146)

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I also have the same problem.  While I do perform Flutter development, I noticed that my disk fills up with such files even on those days/weeks that I do not.

Comment: Having the same problem. The 'fix' doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same problem here

It was fixed after opening Xcode and going to Window/Devices and Simulators.
There select your iPhone and wait for the process of "Copying cache files from device" to finish

Then they can go back to their normal flutter workflow.

Comment: Seems like the issue does not appear now. I did what you wrote, although I could not see  "Copying cache files from device" process. Although I will mark your answer as a solution because the issue never appeared after opening this window. (Maybe it was fixed with macOS update)